# How to Savitzky-Golay filtering for more than one sample/column (R)

Tags: r, filtering

I would like to apply a Savitzky-Golay filter (prospectr package) to a dataset. However, all the examples available run the filter for only one sample (curve with a determined number of wavelengths). Is there anyway I can filter the data of more samples (70 samples) at once?

```
head(ref3)
   wl sev.inox.1 sev.inox.2 sev.inox.3 sev.inox.4 sev.inox.5 sev.inox.6 sev.inox.7
1 270   6.289980   6.113089   6.058497   6.480927   6.682950   6.862938   6.964283
2 271   6.273477   6.076419   6.045145   6.489208   6.676868   6.837713   6.945930
3 272   6.236259   6.047662   6.023476   6.481495   6.654580   6.779429   6.888893
4 273   6.195604   6.004915   6.020849   6.477964   6.622429   6.762655   6.858187
5 274   6.163013   6.013584   5.987006   6.457510   6.606226   6.762517   6.841300
6 275   6.153362   5.994195   5.966318   6.436512   6.607959   6.791893   6.838235     
   
sg <- savitzkyGolay(ref3 , p = 3, w = 11, m = 0)
sg
```

When I try to run this function using all dataset (ref3) instead of limiting to a single sample (e.g. ref3$sev.inox.1, it deletes few samples (columns) instead of wavelengths (rows) from each sample.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe `result <- ref3; result[-1] <- lapply(result[-1], savitzkyGolay, p = 3, w = 11, m = 0)`

Comment: It worked perfectly, Rui Barradas. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually spectral data matrices are organized with observations (samples) in rows and (spectral) variables in columns. The savitzkyGolay function does work for multiple observations. A proper way to call the function for your data is:

```
spc <- t(ref3[, -1])
colnames(spc) <- ref3[, 1]
savitzkyGolay(spc, m = 0, p = 3, w = 11)
```